# How can I use socket.io with Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel, socket.io

I'm having hard time finding any tutorials on how can I integrate socket.io into my Laravel project. I want to build a Laravel chat application.

If there are any other Websocket suggestions rather than socket.io please tell me about them.

Comment: If you're trying to build a Websocket-based Chat, I'll recomend you to use NodeJS + Socket.IO. Laravel is not a good choice to implements realtime applications.

Comment: You can integrate Socket.IO with Laravel only as a client.

Comment: see: https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets